# Parse Order by Descending or by Ascending not working in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am working on a food delivery app and I am stuck at a point where I need to retrieve all the past orders of a particular User. I am able to retrieve the orders but I need to show them as latest first. Below is my code which use to show accordingly. But it doesn't looks like its working. And I have tried solutions posted on stack and other forums, but still, it's not working.

```
let ordersQuery = PFQuery(className: Order)
ordersQuery.whereKey(User, equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: _User, objectId: userObjectId))
ordersQuery.order(byDescending: "orderDate")
ordersQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (result, error) in
}
```

I even tried `ordersQuery.addAscendingOrder("orderDate")`. But no luck

Please help! TIA

Comment: Isn't working at all? Or just the order is wrong? Can you please try `ordersQuery.order(byAscending: "orderDate")` ?

Comment: This works something different. It's not what I want it to be. If we don't use any orderBy, then it shows oldest first and newest last. And if I add byAscending then it messes up all.

Comment: What data type is orderDate?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson string

Comment: Then that might be the reason your sorting doesn’t work. Depending on the format of the date it might not be sortable

Comment: @JoakimDanielson will it work if I change its data type to date?

Comment: Yes. Change the data type to Date and it will.